# Owl Carousel ignoring cover property

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel-2

I am using OwlCarousel 2.3.4 and I have the carousel working but it seems to be ignoring the `cover`property set in my CSS so it is displaying all images side by side rather than as a cover.

I have created a CodePen with my code (I have removed most of the content to keep it small but the Owl Carousel issue is still there) - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/CodeSanity/pen/VwQdMOj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, owl carousel shows 3 items. If you want to customize the item, you can just add an item property where you have initialized the carousel.

something like this one example--

```
` $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    items: 1
  });
});`
```

Comment: I've updated the `ìtems` property but it still shows them side by side rather than cover (I've updated the CodePen)

Comment: .slide-1 {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1024') no-repeat center cover;
} try doing this.

Comment: No, that just makes them disappear, and `.slide-1 { background: url('via.placeholder.com/1024') no-repeat center/cover; } `has no effect

Comment: I was being totally stupid, I set ìtems: 1`and it worked, I had it set to 3